# List to tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list in python, like this:

```
test = ['Vlan101', '1.1.1.0/24', 'Vlan111', '2.1.1.0/24', 'Vlan701', '3.1.1.0/24', 'Vlan703', '4.1.1.0/24', '5.5.5.0/24']
```

I would like tuples created out of it like below:

```
Vlan101,1.1.1.0/24
Vlan111,2.1.1.0/24
Vlan701,3.1.1.0/24
Vlan703,4.1.1.0/24, 5.5.5.0/24
```

The important thing is the last one, which has 2 values for the same key. 
This has been headscratcher for me.

Comment: the last one would be a list tho.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @felipsmartins what do you mean?

Comment: Will the first item in a row always start with `"Vlan"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby()` + `zip()` here:

```
from itertools import groupby

test = [
    "Vlan101",
    "1.1.1.0/24",
    "Vlan111",
    "2.1.1.0/24",
    "Vlan701",
    "3.1.1.0/24",
    "Vlan703",
    "4.1.1.0/24",
    "5.5.5.0/24",
]

print(
    [
        (x,) + y
        for x, y in zip(
            (x_ for x_ in test if x_.startswith("Vlan")),
            (
                tuple(g)
                for k, g in groupby(test, key=lambda x__: x__.startswith("Vlan"))
                if not k
            ),
        )
    ] 
)

# [('Vlan101', '1.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan111', '2.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan701', '3.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan703', '4.1.1.0/24', '5.5.5.0/24')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can use `zip`+`iter` for a generalized way of doing this

```
i = len(test)%2
s = iter(test[:-(2+i)])
[x for x in zip(s,s)] + [tuple(test[-(2+i):])]
```

Outputs

```
[('Vlan101', '1.1.1.0/24'),
 ('Vlan111', '2.1.1.0/24'),
 ('Vlan701', '3.1.1.0/24'),
 ('Vlan703', '4.1.1.0/24', '5.5.5.0/24')]
```

If you want the outer object to also be a `tuple`

```
tuple(x for x in zip(s,s)) + (tuple(test[-(2+i):]),)

(('Vlan101', '1.1.1.0/24'),
 ('Vlan111', '2.1.1.0/24'),
 ('Vlan701', '3.1.1.0/24'),
 ('Vlan703', '4.1.1.0/24', '5.5.5.0/24'))
```

Comment: it doesn't generalize

Comment: Obviously depends on what you believe generalize is. I assumed it works for both all pairs and all pairs + triple at the end

Comment: take 2 pairs in between and it breaks. OP might not needed it but just mentioning.

Comment: Yeah we can think of numerous scenarios and no solutions will cover them all ;) this assumed following structure: `key1,val1,key2,val2,...` thanks for commenting

Answer (score 2):

The second, third, etc. elements of your tuples look like ip-addresses. You can use a regex to recognise the specific format. *(I'm taking the risk of assuming you'll be playing around with ip-addresses)*.

Here's another solution, less cleaner than [Rafael's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624980/10239789) or [RoadRunner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53625086/10239789), but allows for an arbitrary number of addresses.

```
import re

test = [
        'Vlan101',
        '1.1.1.0/24',
        'Vlan111',
        '2.1.1.0/24',
        'Vlan701', 
        '3.1.1.0/24', 
        'Vlan703', 
        '4.1.1.0/24', 
        '5.5.5.0/24']

result = [[]]  # we first store the stuff as lists to allow for appending
for item in test:

    # matches ipaddresses with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
    if re.match(r'\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3}/\d+', item):
        result[-1].append(item)    # appends an ipaddress
    else:
        result.append([item])      # appends a new 'Vlan...' (i.e. anything but an ipaddress)

tups = list(map(tuple, result))    # cast each of the lists into tuples

print(result)
print(tups)
```

Output:

```
[[], ['Vlan101', '1.1.1.0/24'], ['Vlan111', '2.1.1.0/24'], ['Vlan701', '3.1.1.0/24'], ['Vlan703', '4.1.1.0/24', '5.5.5.0/24']]
[(), ('Vlan101', '1.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan111', '2.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan701', '3.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan703', '4.1.1.0/24', '5.5.5.0/24')]
```

The empty `[]` and `()` are there at the beginning in case your `test` list starts off immediately with addresses (it's to provide a fall-back for `result[-1]`).

If you wish to remove those results simply do a slice

```
print(tups[1:])
```

Output:

```
[('Vlan101', '1.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan111', '2.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan701', '3.1.1.0/24'), ('Vlan703', '4.1.1.0/24', '5.5.5.0/24')]
```